# Tracking subdomains with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have two subdomains for my business: sniphq.com and app.sniphq.com.

I want to track these subdomains separately in Google Analytics. [This page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html) tells me how to set up filters and everything, which is great, but how do I actually view the traffic for each subdomain and stuff like that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply visit [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/) website. Create a new profile. Click "New Property". There you'll have all the options to add home site, setup filters everything. Once you're setup, you can track all the traffic of all your subdomains.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've already done all that stuff. The part I don't know how to do is the "track all the traffic of all your subdomains" part. I'm seeing the traffic, etc. for sniphq.com (and my other TLDs) but not app.sniphq.com.

Comment: I think the trick is to create multiple profiles, each having individual filters that *includes* the traffic from a subdomain depending on the filter. And edit the script accordingly.

Comment: That didn't work, either.